# Ubuntu 22.04 lagging after installation

Tags: drivers, kernel, intel-graphics

I used Ubuntu 22.04 from release and now I move to new laptop Huawei MateBook 14s (HKF-WXX).

Immediatly during installation and after installation system permanent lagging. I found out that if I set 'nomodeset' flag in grub settings I switch to simplified graphic driver llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6) from Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) than system work normally. Also I found that Ubuntu 20.04 worked fine and I can update it to Ubuntu 22.04 and work without lagging, but after some time (I think after Ubuntu kernel update) system again starts lagging. I tied downgrade kernel to version after upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04, but I don't understand how to do this.

Laptop is on Intel Core i7-12700H. What I could do or what information could I receive to solve problem? Also I can say that same problem I have with Manjaro Gnome.

Also I noticed that with new kernel possibility to change refresh rate disappear.

Comment: Is it Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: So your question is about Ubuntu Core 22?  (The *year* products such as 22 are different to the *year.month* products (ie. 22.04 or 22.10)).  You didn't indicate which kernel stacks you're using, as 20.04 LTS using the HWE kernel stack (5.15) is the same kernel stack as used by 22.04 LTS if using GA (5.15).

Comment: 22.04, thanks for editing

Comment: What graphics does it have? What kernel are you using?

Comment: Graphics: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2). Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic